# Installing MySQL Native Driver

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get mysqli_result::fetch_all() to work but I'm out of my depth and butting my head against a wall. This is all being done on remote server and I'm using PuTTY to connect. The internet is telling me to install MySQL Native Driver using the following lines of code:

```
php ./configure --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
```

What I'm getting back is "Could not open input file: ./configure". What do I do now?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: try one of the following sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd or sudo yum install php5-mysqlnd

Comment: @exussum: both of those return sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Comment: @Machavity: I don't actually know, it's not my site. They're giving me access to set up a page I wrote that needs websockets. Horrendous amount of fiddling I've done with it today...

Comment: do you have root access ? if so log in as root repeat without the sudo

Comment: I don't have root access, but I tried those anyway. The yum one returns this:
CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf

Comment: The other says apt-get cannot be found

Comment: Sounds like EL5 or EL6. Try `cat /etc/redhat-release`

Comment: returns cat: /etc/redhat-release: No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like the operating system is nginx

Comment: We cannot talk you through installing something on a server we have no information about when you have apparently zero knowledge of the domain. You should really contact someone who can administer that server and/or get some more basic information about that thing first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the `mysqlnd` extension over the package manager. You should look at the documentation of your specific operation system.

But on APT systems you can use:

```
apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

under CentOS or better Red Hat package Manager:

```
yum install php-mysqlnd
```

when you are root you don't need the sudo command. When you are logged on as a normal user you have to write `sudo` before your command.

A good tutorial how to install the extension:

http://blog.ahughes.org/?p=602

Comment: Good stuff but the stock yum package for mysqlnd is `php-mysqlnd`. Check out the [remi repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) for how it's normally done.

Comment: Looks like the operating system is nginx

Comment: @Jamesypoo Nope, it's not, that's merely your web server. Don't you have a server admin you can talk to?